# Prove that there exists $c\neq0$ such that $h(x)=x+cf(x$) is injective

Tags: real-analysis

$f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable, $f'(x)$ bounded. Prove that there exists $c\neq0$ such that $h(x)=x+cf(x$) is injective

I really have no idea how to do this, i just want a hint to prove it

Comment: You need a c, such that h'(x) doesn't change sign throughout the domain.

Comment: Let c be the negative inverse of the greatest value of f’(x)

Comment: You are supposed to make the connection between invertibility and monotonicity

Comment: How it would be the derivative of $h$ if it is, for instance, a increasing function?